# Sympy: Is there a way to create the PDF of a Truncated Normal Distribution in Sympy?

Tags: sympy

I want to create a function that is the PDF of a truncated normal distribution.

With this kind of PDF I need to calculate others PDFs, that are obtainable with integration.

I want to know if is it possible to make this PDF in Sympy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take the formula found at the Wikipedia page and write it in Sympy.  This will need the `erf`  function, which might be a bit nasty to deal with,

Comment: Hey. I solve it with Piecewise funciton (sympy.Piecewise). `code` pdf_gauss_trunc = smp.Piecewise((0, x<=a), (normal_adjusted, (x>a) & (x<b)), (0, x>=b))

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments, you can do that via sympy with:

```
pdf_gauss_trunc = smp.Piecewise((0, x<=a), (normal_adjusted, (x>a) & (x<b)), (0, x>=b))
```

where `a` and `b` are the extremes.